# How to return a promise from redux thunk action and consume it in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, firebase-authentication, redux-thunk

I am using React+Redux+Redux Thunk + Firebase authentication. Writing code in Typescript.
My action is:

```
//Type for redux-thunk. return type for rdux-thunk action creators
type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  IStoreState, //my store state
  null,
  Action<userActionTypes>
>

export const signInWithEmailAndPasword =(email:string, pasword:string): AppThunk=>{
  return async (dispatch)=>{
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pasword).then(response=>{
      if(response.user){
        const docRef = db.collection("users").doc(response.user.uid);
          docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
              const userData = doc.data(); //user data from firebase DB
               //if user exists in DB, dispatch
               dispatch({
                type: userActionTypes.SIGN_IN_USER,
                payload: userData
              })
              return userData;
            } else {
                // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                console.log("No such document!");
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(err=> dispatch(setUserError(err.message)))
  }
}
```

My SignIn component, where i am dispatching this above action:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
//some other imports
//...
//
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { signInWithEmailAndPasword } from '../../redux/actions/userActions';


interface ISignInState {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
const SignIn = (props:any) => {

  const [values, setValues] = useState<ISignInState>({ email: '', password: '' })

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleInputChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    const { name, value } = e.currentTarget;
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value })
  }

  const handleFormSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const { email, password } = values;
    dispatch(signInWithEmailAndPasword(email, password))
//// -> gives error: Property 'then' does not exist on 
//// type 'ThunkAction<void, IStoreState, null, Action<userActionTypes>>'
    .then(()=>{ 
      props.history.push('/');
      setValues({ email: '', password: '' })
    })

  }

  return (<div>Sign in UI JSX stuff</div>)
```

So when i try to use `.then()` after `dispatch(signInWithEmailAndPasword(email, password))` it gives an error `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'ThunkAction<void, IStoreState, null, Action<userActionTypes>>'`
  So how can i return promise from redux action and chain a `.then()` on it? I always assumed that thunk actions return promises by default.
 Thanks for your help
Edit:
Temporary soluton was to use `any` as return type of above action:

```
export const signInWithEmailAndPasword = (email:string, pasword:string):any =>{
  return async (dispatch: any)=>{
    try {
      const response = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pasword)
      if(response.user){
        const userInDb = await getUserFromDB(response.user)
        dispatch(userSignIn(userInDb))
        return userInDb
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(setUserError(error.message))
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't want to use `any`

Comment: You can await thunks - looks like it might just be typescript error on the part of the library? What if you just did an `async/await` inside that function

Comment: IDEALLY however, the thunk action would dispatch another action based on the `then` that you passed in, rather than doing it in your component.

Comment: That thunk is really gross by the way, you're using promises, but nesting them instead of returning them, you aren't returning your top level promise (which would also be a problem, even if the typescript error didn't exist).....yikes all over.

Comment: I just need it to redirect after successful response.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `return` before this line:

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pasword).then(response=>{
```

So it would be:

```
export const signInWithEmailAndPasword =(email:string, pasword:string): AppThunk=>{
  return async (dispatch)=>{
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pasword).then(response=>{
```

It should work.

Comment: I tried that also. it didn't work. The problem is in return type of that action. I have it as `AppThunk`. But if i use `any` , the problem goes away and i can chain `.then()` on it

Comment: I am not familiar with TS type system but I think it should be Promise<return_type>, for example Promise<number>.

Comment: and of course Promise type should be the type of your returned promise, not thunk.

Answer (score 1):

`AppThunk<Promise<void>>`

---

You need to explicitly declare the AppThunks return type, which in this case should be a `Promise` containing nothing. You have already made it async so just make sure to enter the correct AppThunk return type

```
export const signInWithEmailAndPassword = (email: string, password: string): AppThunk<Promise<void>> => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
      // do stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Thunks return functions, not promises. For this you could look at `redux-promise`. But to be honest if your doing something this complex you would be much better off using `redux-saga`.

Another approach would be to use the concepts behind `redux-api-middleware` to create your own custom redux middleware. I have done this in the past to connect a message queue to redux.

Comment: PS on a slightly related note you might find this interesting https://jrsinclair.com/articles/2017/indentation-is-the-enemy-less-complex-javascript/

Comment: Dispatching a `thunk` doesn't return a function, it returns whatever the `thunk` returns. Introducing the steep learning curve and crazy complexity of `redux-saga` is massive overkill for such a little issue.

Comment: Thunks just lead to crazy unmaintable code, that example has 10 levels of indentation in it! Sagas are pretty straight forward and the concepts behind them can be picked up in a day by any moderately competent coder. How would you write a unit test for that Thunk?

Comment: Indentations are mainly from IF statements. I added them to avoid TS null checks. There are two functions there in that actions function. One for signing in one for DB check. Again I could separate them. But i will do it after get rid of my main problem.

Comment: Thunks don't lead to crazy unmaintanable code - crazy unmaintainable code leads to crazy unmaintainable code (like the OPs). It wasn't crazy unmaintainable just because it was a thunk. I've never had a problem unit testing a thunk, keep it under 7-10 lines and you'll be fine.